# Issue with QTimer cashing python crash

Tags: python, qt

I am having issues with python crashing when exceptions are raised inside a QTimer callback. Below is a small example showing this

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QTimer, pyqtSlot)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication)

class MainWindow (QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.timer_call)
        self.timer.start(1000)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def timer_call(self):
        print ("Called")
        x={}
        x[2]

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main = MainWindow()
main.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When run this shows the following:

Called
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/gtscan.py", line 21, in timer_call
    x[2]
KeyError: 2
Aborted (core dumped)

Version of software used are (all from Arch Linux builds):

Python 3.4.3
Qt version: 5.5.0
PyQt version: 5.5
SIP version: 4.16.9

Can anyone help this please - it is not the KeyError I am looking for help on - it is why this causes the python Aborted (core dumped) error.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't get a segmentation fault in my case. Python 3.4.0, PyQt5 5.2.1, SIP: 4.15.5. It just prints an exception message at each timeout. Application doesn't crash.

Comment: Just a style note: why are you doing `from smth import (this, and, this)` (with braces)? Wouldn't it be nicer without them?

Comment: I don’t know about pyqt, but in c++, exceptions must not leave slots, otherwise Qt’s event loop will catch it and abort (I think that’s what it still does)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this has been pointed out to me:

As of `PyQt` v5.5 unhandled exceptions result in a call to `qFatal()`, 
More details about this, please check in [this link](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/incompatibilities.html#pyqt-v5-5).

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in below lines

```
x={}    // this is empty dictionary
x[2]    // here you are trying to retrieve key 2's value
```

As python is not able to retrieve the value of `key` 2, so it is crashing with `KeyError`

`Segmentation fault` / `core dump` happens when a python tries to access a memory beyond reach.

Comment: I expect that error - but not the Aborted (core dumped) exception - I have updated the original message to highlight the real issue

Comment: @JohnAlan: put in `try...except` block then core dump wont come.

Comment: Again I realise this - but a core cump is never good and to me indicates a real issue somewhere which needs fixing?

Comment: The KeyError should never cause python to create a segmentation error - it will just propagate the exception. The segmentation error in this case is caused by a change in PyQt 5.5 which now calls qFatal() on an unhandled exception which will then call abort() - hence the issue I saw.